# language localization in xib/ib does not work

Tags: iphone

I am working on the localization of one of my project.
The function NSLocalizedString in XCode does work.
But when I switch the language setting, it look likes the app does not switch to relevant fr/en/jp file of mainwindow.xib, help.html etc.

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a xib file for each localization, put your mainwindow.xib with french text in fr folder, the en version in the en folder etc.

For more information: [Interface Builder User Guide: Localization](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/IB_UserGuide/LocalizingNibFiles/LocalizingNibFiles.html)